# C# ComboBox: выпадающее меню по нажатию правой клавиши мыши

Tags: c#, wpf

`ComboBox` наследует событие `Click` (левая клавиша мыши) от `Control`. Мне нужно сделать вывод выпадающего меню по клику правой клавиши. Как это сделать проще, без созданию пользовательского элемента управления унаследованного от `Control`?

Comment: Вам нужно контестное меню? Если да, то, у TextBox есть свойство ContextMenu, возможно, что это то, что Вам надо.

Comment: При чем же здесь контекстное меню? ComboBox это же поле с встроенным выпадающим списком! Он открывается при щелчке левой клавишей мыши. А мне нужно сделать правой.

Comment: Ой, извините, почему-то прочитал TextBox.

Comment: Стоит сразу указывать правильные тэги.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать событие `MouseRightButtonUp`. Если нужно, то дополнительно можно вычислять, что кликнули именно по кнопке со стрелочкой.

Запретить открывания списка явно нельзя. Можно только закрывать его сразу после открытия.

Code behind:

```
private bool _shouldOpenDropDown;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    comboBox.DropDownOpened += ComboBox_DropDownOpened;
    comboBox.MouseRightButtonUp += ComboBox_MouseRightButtonUp;
}

private void ComboBox_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_shouldOpenDropDown)
    {
        _shouldOpenDropDown = false;
    }
    else
    {
        comboBox.IsDropDownOpen = false;
    }
}

private void ComboBox_MouseRightButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    _shouldOpenDropDown = true;
    comboBox.IsDropDownOpen = true;
}
```

Comment: Я пытался так, но DroppedDown такого свойства нет...

Comment: Кстати, уточняю, у меня WPF приложение.

Comment: @AVM обновил ответ.

Comment: попробую так...

Comment: Нет, не помогает (((

Comment: @AVM обновил еще раз. Теперь точно работает, пришлось открыть Студию :).

Comment: Спасибо, теперь работает. MouseRightButtonUp видимо нужно было.

Comment: @AVM не за что! Можете отметить ответ как верный (галочка слева от ответа).

Comment: Но вот еще вопрос - как запретить вывод выпадающего меню при нажатии левой клавиши?

Comment: private void ComboBox_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        } так не получается

Comment: @AVM обновил ответ.

Comment: наверно, можно и так... Хотя флаг вводить в моей ситуации лучше не надо.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте свойство IsDropDownOpen контрола СomboBox для управления выпадающим списком.

Попробуйте так:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    comboBox.MouseUp += comboBox_MouseUp;
}

private void comboBox_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Released)
        comboBox.IsDropDownOpen = true;
}
```